# Fetch entire data from Celery task

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, django-celery

I am currently using **celery** in my Django project. Below are my **views.py** and **tasks.py** files.

**views.py**

```
def status_codes(request):
try:
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    urls = linksextraction(url)
    url_codes.objects.all().delete()
    for each_url in urls:
        res = url_status_codes.delay(each_url[1])
    while (res.status == 'PENDING'):# waiting till all tasks are completed
        pass
# Do manipulations from db data
```

**tasks.py**

```
@app.task
def url_status_codes(url):
    r = requests.head(url)
    status_code = r.status_code
    spell_words = spellcheck(url, 'English--en')
    if (not spell_words):
        spell_words = 'NA'
    data = url_codes(status_code=status_code, url=url, spell_words=spell_words)
    data.save() # Saving in Database
```

From above code snippets, **I am saving results achevied in tasks.py in database** and when all tasks are completed, i am fetching the results from db and doing manipulations.

Is there any way to get all results in tasks.py to views.py without having saved to db.

Comment: If you wait in your view for the tasks to complete, there is no point in doing them asynchronously in the first place. The whole point of doing that is so that the view can return quickly. You are even doing additional harm by eagerly waiting.

Comment: i got your point but if i dont wait, the view will be returned with incomplete data.....is there any way to get all results in tasks.py to views.py without having saved to db.?

Comment: Yes, don't call the task, but execute the code form the task synchronously and return the results directly. Generally, you should return quickly and have spinner or sth. in your template and load the data via AJAX once the tasks have finished.

Comment: you mean, instead of giving the function name of views.py in the AJAX call, you want me to directly give the function name of tasks.py and return there itself? will it work?

Comment: You can try ZeroMQ (ZMQ) in python, it is very easy to implement publish-subscriber structure.